# importlib.import_module is not a package

Tags: python

update.py:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--data_file")
job_args = parser.parse_known_args()[0]
imported = importlib.import_module(job_args.data_file)

CURIE_BLR.py
testbed = "CURIE_BLR"
sockets = [
    "10.64.127.135:2005:Fugazi",
    "10.64.127.135:2006:Radium",
    "10.64.127.135:2007:Thallium",
    "10.64.127.135:2008:Thorium",
    "10.64.127.135:2009:Uranium",
    "10.64.127.135:2011:Neptune",
    "10.64.127.135:2033:Promethium"
]
```

> `python update_topo_status.py --data_file CURIE_BLR.py`

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'CURIE_BLR.py'; 'CURIE_BLR' is not a package
```

Comment: Line `CURIE_BLR.py` is not a valid Python code

Comment: "import_module" expects a module name without file suffix ".py".

Answer (score 0):

You have to import like this:

```
import argparse
import CURIE_BLR

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--data_file")
job_args = parser.parse_known_args()[0]
imported = importlib.import_module(job_args.data_file)


testbed = "CURIE_BLR"
sockets = [
    "10.64.127.135:2005:Fugazi",
    "10.64.127.135:2006:Radium",
    "10.64.127.135:2007:Thallium",
    "10.64.127.135:2008:Thorium",
    "10.64.127.135:2009:Uranium",
    "10.64.127.135:2011:Neptune",
    "10.64.127.135:2033:Promethium"
]
```

Also your file `CURIE_BLR.py` should be on the same folder/path where your other python packages/modules are present.